# Sort months array backwords from today

Tags: php

I have the following array and need to sort it from current month backwards - All I get is NULL

Here's what i'm trying:

```
$months = array(
'January' => 0,
'February' => 0,
'March' => 0,
'April' => 0,
'May' => 0,
'June' => 0,
'July ' => 0,
'August' => 0,
'September' => 0,
'October' => 0,
'November' => 0,
'December' => 0,
);

$current = date('F');
$start = array_search($current, $months);

$toshow = array();
$total = 0;
for($i = $start; $total < 12; $i--)
{
if($i == 0)
{
    $i = 12;
}

$toshow[] = $months[$i];
$total++;
}

var_dump($toshow);
```

And the result I get is:

```
array(12) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> NULL [11]=> NULL }
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @air4x Hi, expected output is: 'September' => 0, 'August' => 0, 'July' => 0, etc etc

Comment: @DarrenSweeney there are 6 answers none of them works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

use  the `krsort()`: This function sorts an array by key in reverse order maintaining the correlation with the value, this function is useful for associative array.

```
krsort($months );

print_r($months );
```

[LIve EXample](http://codepad.org/VZacZlZl)

Comment: OP wants the array sorted in reverse from the CURRENT month.  If the current month is anything but December, I don't think this would work.

Answer (score 0):

krsort($toshow = cal_info(CAL_GREGORIAN));` would give you a reverse sorted array of months.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$current = date('F');
$arr = array_combine(range(1,12), array_keys($months));
$start = array_search($current, $arr);
//$start = date('n');
for ($i=$start;$i<=12;$i++) {
  $arr_sorted[$arr[$i]] = $months[$arr[$i]];
}
for ($i=1;$i<$start;$i++) {
  $arr_sorted[$arr[$i]] = $months[$arr[$i]];
}
print_r($arr_sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
$months = array(
'January' => 0,
'February' => 0,
'March' => 0,
'April' => 0,
'May' => 0,
'June' => 0,
'July ' => 0,
'August' => 0,
'September' => 0,
'October' => 0,
'November' => 0,
'December' => 0,
);

$current = date('F');
$keys = array_keys($months);
$start = array_search($current, $keys);
$toshow = array();


for($i=$start+12; $i>$start; $i--) {
  $key = $i % 12;
  $toshow[$keys[$key]] = $months[$keys[$key]];
}

var_dump( $toshow );
```

Outputs:

```
array(12) { 
  ["September"]=> int(0) 
  ["August"]=> int(0) 
  ["July "]=> int(0) 
  ["June"]=> int(0) 
  ["May"]=> int(0) 
  ["April"]=> int(0) 
  ["March"]=> int(0) 
  ["February"]=> int(0) 
  ["January"]=> int(0) 
  ["December"]=> int(0) 
  ["November"]=> int(0) 
  ["October"]=> int(0) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why need to take array with static values and then sort it backward. You can make your array itself backward as below**

There is no need to take this array

```
$months = array(
'January' => 0,
'February' => 0,
'March' => 0,
'April' => 0,
'May' => 0,
'June' => 0,
'July ' => 0,
'August' => 0,
'September' => 0,
'October' => 0,
'November' => 0,
'December' => 0,
);
```

You can directly make $months array backwards.

```
$months = array();
$currentMonth = (int)date('m');

for($x = $currentMonth; $x >=$currentMonth-12; $x--) {
    $months[date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1))] = 0;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($months);
```

Now your array itself look as you expected

```
Array
(
    [September] => 0
    [August] => 0
    [July] => 0
    [June] => 0
    [May] => 0
    [April] => 0
    [March] => 0
    [February] => 0
    [January] => 0
    [December] => 0
    [November] => 0
    [October] => 0
)
```

See output: http://codepad.org/WuBBYeUh

Comment: this does not retain the values in the original array!

Comment: @JvdBerg i understand your point but there is no need to take array from janurary to december and then check current month then reorganize whole array ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Your code is not correct because you fill the result with `0` instead of the value from the original array.

Comment: @JvdBerg i think you didn't understand my answer. see edited answer now

Comment: `$months[date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1))] = 0;` <-- hardcoded `zero` instead of the original value from `$months`